# Can't convert SQL VARBINARY to byte[] correctly and convert to Image in ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, image-processing

Here is what I'm doing:

```
public static MVC_Picture GetPictureRecord(int pictureID)
{
    int pictureId = pictureID;
    MVC_Picture _picture = new MVC_Picture(); //object that stores name and array

    var connString = db.connString;
    string cmdText = "SELECT PictureName, PictureImage FROM Picture WHERE CONVERT(INT, ID) =@pictureId;";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection))
        {
            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
            param1.ParameterName = "@pictureId";
            param1.Value = pictureId;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                _picture.Id = pictureId;
                _picture.PictureName = Convert.ToString(dr["PictureName"]);
                _picture.PictureImage = (byte[])(dr["PictureImage"]); //Problem
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return _picture; 
}
```

When I convert to `byte[]` I get something like: `{byte[4354567]}`

I'm then trying to convert array to `Image` like so:

```
Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(_picture.PictureImage);
ViewModel.FeaturedImage = img;
```

And in View I use:

```
<img src="@ViewModel.FeaturedImage" alt="Featured Image" />
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<img src=`... has to point to an image file by its *path*, eg `<img src="/myImage.jpg">`. You can't stick a binary representation of the image in the `src` and have it work.

So you could either write those binary images out to disk somewhere (you probably don't want to do that, as then you're duplicating the data, and would have to manage synchronizing).

Or you could create some kind of image handler, so the `<img src=` would be something like: `<img src="/myHandler/imageId"`, and then have the handler read the binary data from the database and respond with the image.

This is an MVC controller action that I've used in the past to read a binary PDF out of the DB, and return it as a file. This is in my `Competition` controller. If this was returning an image, you could call it something like:

`<img src="Competition/ViewJobDescription?competitionId=1234" />`

```
    public ActionResult ViewJobDescription(int competitionId)
    {
        string errorMsg = "";
        var competition = new DBModel.Competition();
        try
        {               
            competition = DBModel.Competition.GetCompetition(competitionId);
            if (competition != null && competition.AttachmentContent != null)
            {
                byte[] fileData = competition.AttachmentContent;
                string filename = competition.AttachmentTitle + ".pdf";
                return File(fileData, "application/pdf", filename);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMsg += "An error occured: " + ex.Message;
            LogFile err = new LogFile();
            err.CreateErrorLog(errorMsg);

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, errorMsg);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: I bind to an actual Image, not binary.

Comment: No, an `Image` is still a binary representation of the image. `<img src=` requires a *path* to the image, not the image itself

Comment: damn. didn't know that. so my array is correct? it's just the reference of img src that is broken?

Comment: Yes - I'll update my answer with what I've done in the past to return a pdf; you could do the same with your image.

Comment: ok. thanks a lot, I'm reading about paths to the images in asp.net now to get through this stuff.

Comment: It's really going to depend on your application as to whether it's better or not, but in general, I prefer storing my binary data in database like what you're doing here. It will allow your solution to be more portable, and with referential integrity, you can clean up documents, images, etc more easily. Of course it totally depends on the scale of your solution, what you're doing with it, etc.